# Easiest way to dyanmically load a DIV on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have a relatively simple question here.

What I require is this; I need to have a page with 5 buttons at the top and a DIV beneath them (initially hidden). When a button is clicked, it loads content into the DIV (in the form of another DIV)
eg.

```
[Button 1] [Button 2] [Button 3] [Button 4] [Button 5] //5 buttons or links

<div id="content">
 // area for content to be loaded
</div>

<div id="content1">
//could be a table or image
</div>

<div id="content2">
//could be a table or image
</div>

<div id="content3">
//could be a table or image
</div>

<div id="content4">
//could be a table or image
</div>

<div id="content5">
//could be a table or image
</div>
```

In the above example, when the user loads the page they see 5 buttons. If they press button 5, it loads the "content5" DIV inside of the "content" DIV eg.

```
<div id="content">
 <div id="content5">
</div>
</div>
```

If another button is selected it loads it's content.

Can be achieved with jQuery or simple JavaScript.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want the content from previous button clicks to remain inside `#content` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind a click handler on all of the buttons. Smart way in this particular example would be, to use the index of the elements to determine which `div` belongs to a `button`.

```
$('button').bind('click', function() {
    $('div#content').html($('div#content' + ($(this).index()+1)).html());
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/8f8jt/

This will add an click event handler to all `<button>` nodes. On click, it looks for the index of the current clicked button ([`.index()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/index/)) and uses this value to query for the accordant `<div>` elements id. Once found, use [`.html()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get and set the value.

Comment: i was thinking the same thing but you posted earlier...any way upvaoted for the answer

Comment: That's great, functionality is perfect. However I need it modified to work with jquery-1.4.2.min.js. Any help appreciated, thanks a lot jAndy :)

Comment: A quick question, I'm assuming its fine to replace $('button') with a div class for the click action? Say $('btn-red')?

Comment: @Sam: the should work fine with 1.4.2 and yes, you can replace it by any selector you need.

Comment: Hmm, can't see to be able to get it working with 1.4.2min. Copied and paste the exact html, referenced 1.4.2min in the header and copied the following into the header:

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('button').bind('click', function() {
    $('div#content').html($('div#content' + ($(this).index()+1)).html());
});
</script>

Comment: very elegant solution that involving the index of element

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [jQueryUI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), but it requires additional script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $("#content").html(("#content1").html());
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    $("#content").html(("#content2").html());
});

// etc
```

This way clears any existing content and copies the correct div into the main #content div.

Comment: I'm guessing that  Sam doesn't want content from a previous button click to remain when you click another button. (however that's a pure assumption.)

Comment: I was in the middle of editing and iteratively improving it :)  After a few edits it was almost exactly the same as another answer, so I've stopped there.