# How to load js files and apply to a div dynamically?

Tags: javascript

If I had a HTML page that was completely clean, how can I with Javascript be able to click on a button located in the body of the page that dynamically adds a div and the appropriate .js scripts to include in order to show a basic workin openlayers map? Any sample would be appreciated. Its easy for me to click on a button to dynamic add a div with id "map", but I am not sure how to get dynamically include the .js script to have it be applied to the div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and place a `<div>` when user clicks a button:
[Easiest way to dyanmically load a DIV on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883282/easiest-way-to-dyanmically-load-a-div-on-button-click)

Dynamically load JavaScript source:
[Ways to add javascript files dynamically in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751620/ways-to-add-javascript-files-dynamically-in-a-page)

Comment: What is recommended for the dynamic loading of the JS that does something to the created DIV?